# Check if a cell is filled with 10 digit number

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, cell, is-empty

I am adding a 10 digit number to a particular cell in Excel.

If true, I want to run a macro.
If false, a msgbox with a text.

```vb
Sub Run_PNR()

If Cells(E, 7).Value = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Enter Correct PNR Number")
Else
    Shell "explorer.exe " & Range("d25").Text
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "ABCDEFGHIJ" has ten digits, but it's not a number. "1234567890" has ten digits and is a number. But what about "0000067890"? And in case it's abbreviated to "67890"? Are (one of) these ten digit numbers?

Comment: @dominique add appositive phrase in before 0000067890 digit. its not abbreviated the digit. like '0000067890

Comment: Are you wanting to check cell E7? If so, that's not how you do it. Use `Range("E7")`.

Comment: `Range("E7").Value Like String(10, "#")`

Comment: @Dominique "ABCDEFGHIJ" has ten *characters*, but no digits...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Val` function to convert the cell content to a number and check it's value:

```
Dim cellVal as Long
cellVal = Val(ActiveSheet.Cells(7, "E").Value)
If cellVal < 1000000000 Or cellVal > 9999999999 Then
    MsgBox ("Enter Correct PNR Number")
Else
    (do whatever needs to be done...)
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Cells(7,"E")'? I'm getting a type mismatch otherwise.

Comment: @Notus_Panda you are right. Against my habit just C&P code from OP without checking.

Comment: This does not handle 0000000001.

Comment: @Sam: 0000000001 is not a number (it's either a string or the number 1 with a special formatting). But that's the main problem: OP missed to tell what data they exactly have.

Comment: Oh, yes it is. Even Excel says so. `Debug.Print IsNumeric("0000000001")` results in true. In any case, when a computer asks for a ten digit number, it is almost without exception zero padded.

Comment: `"0000000001"` is obviously *not* a number (what do you think the quotes stands for?). It's a string, occupying 10 bytes of memory. If you enter 000000001 in Excel, it will convert it to the number 1. If you want `000000001` as String, you either need to put a single quote character or format the cell as text. In both cases `Vartype` will return `vbString`.

Answer (score 1):

This code for alpha and numeric.

```
Sub Run_PNR()
    If Len(Range("E7").value) <> 10 Then
    MsgBox ("Enter Correct PNR Number")
    Else
    Shell "explorer.exe " & Range("d25").Text
    End If
    End Sub
```

This code for numeric only.

```
If IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Range("E7").value) Then
If Len(ActiveSheet.Range("E7").value) <> 10 Then
MsgBox ("Enter Correct PNR Number")
Else
Shell "explorer.exe " & Range("d25").Text
End If
Else
MsgBox ("Enter Number only")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That would accept also non-numeric values

Comment: yes its accept that, may be in future they want to add alpha numeric its help too.

Comment: This would allow "3.14159265" to be entered..

Comment: not allowed its allow whole numbers only.

Comment: `3.14159265` is numeric though. I'm saying your code would allow it and shouldn't.

Comment: yes it allow , but PNR number not coming with double values. that validation not necessary for this.

Answer (score 1):

`RegExp` is a option to validate 10 digit number.

```vb
Sub Run_PNR()
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\d{10}"
        If .Test(Trim(Cells(7, "E").Value)) Then
            Shell "explorer.exe " & Range("d25").Text
        Else
            MsgBox ("Enter Correct PNR Number")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```